# Subtracting row wise in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with over 2000 rows and just two columns. I want to create two new column of interval from an existing date column.The interdate1 is the difference between two date and ends when the year runs out. Starting as 0 in the subsequent year. While the interdate2 continues without resetting to zero when it encounters a new year.

Data set A is what I presently read into R but data setB is the result I want.

```
DatasetA
date               cost
3/20/1990           0.89
3/21/1990           1.98
3/22/1990           2.0
6/24/1990           0.74
1/18/1991           0.54
1/20/1991           0.56
```

Expected Result

```
date               cost         interdate1  interdate2
3/20/1990           0.89           0           0
3/21/1990           1.98           1           1 
3/22/1990           2.0            1           1  
6/24/1990           0.74           2           2
1/18/1991           0.54           0           189
1/20/1991           0.56           2           190
```

Please I am new to R and trying to work my way around a data set. I have spent the whole day trying to get this to work but I couldn't. Please I would appreciate if someone could take a look and help me out.

Comment: Are you sure your input data is correct? Shouldn't row 4 of date be `"3/24/1990"` and shouldn't the final two rows of interdate2 be `300` and `302`? If not I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @ SimonO101 those at not the original data set am working with. But they are in that form and I am sure you understand what my question is. Thanks

Comment: No, it is not obvious without real data. The day difference could mean two things: number of day between consecutive rows, or number of days from the first row. It should not be too hard to compute these manually and update your question. That will clarify any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Probably like this (but you have unaddressed issues as pointed out by Simon)

```
padded.diff <- function(x) c(0L, diff(x))

within(DatasetA, {
  date        <- as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
  date.int    <- as.integer(date)
  interdate2b <- date.int - date.int[1]
  interdate2a <- padded.diff(date.int)
  interdate1  <- ave(date.int, format(date, "%Y"), FUN = padded.diff)
  date.int    <- NULL # do not report
})
```

(I think `interdate2a` or `interdate2b` should be what you want, just not sure which one from your description.)

Comment: what if I for interdate1 inside of resetting zero when it encounters a new year, it just subtract the previous date and continues eg moving from 12/31/1990 to 01/03/1991, instead of starting as 0 in 1991 it counts the difference between 12/31/1990 and 01/03/1991 and returns the value 3.

Comment: what you just described is my `interdate2a`.

Comment: interdate1 and interdate2a produce similar output

Comment: You are right. Thanks. You have any document or link to any that I can read on this? Since I would be working pretty much on data set of this nature.

Comment: You can access the doc of each function by typing `?within`, `?as.Date`, `?ave`, etc. in your terminal. Also, if you are new to R, the R introduction is a must-read. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1$date<-as.Date(df1$date,"%m/%d/%Y")
   df1$interdate2<-df1$date - df1$date[1]
x<-as.Date("1/01/1991","%m/%d/%Y")
 df1$interdate1<-with(df1,ifelse(date<x,date-date[1],date-date[5]))

> df1
        date cost interdate2 interdate1
1 1990-03-20 0.89     0 days          0
2 1990-03-21 1.98     1 days          1
3 1990-03-22 2.00     2 days          2
4 1990-06-24 0.74    96 days         96
5 1991-01-18 0.54   304 days          0
6 1991-01-20 0.56   306 days          2
```

Comment: I think `df1$interdate2` should just be `df1$date - df1$date[1]`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code you suggested but I got the following error message "Error in r[i1]-r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L]:

Comment: @ user18143: It should run fine

Comment: I tried the code but my result is in this form [2136] "1990-11-15" "1990-11-23" "1990-11-27" "1990-11-29" "1990-11-29"
[2141] "1990-11-30" "1990-11-30" "1990-12-04" "1990-12-05" "1990-12-06"
[2146] "1990-12-07" "1990-12-08" "1990-12-09" "1990-12-09" "1990-12-10"
[2151] "1990-12-14" "1990-12-15" "1990-12-16" "1990-12-17" "1990-12-19"
[2156] "1990-12-20" "1990-12-21" "1990-12-21" "1990-12-22" "1990-12-23"
[2161] "1990-12-23" "1990-12-24" "1990-12-27" "1990-12-30" "1990-12-30"
[2166] "1990-12-30" "1990-12-31". I can I have it just as stated above?

Comment: You need to first convert your date variable into date format before doing any other operation,did you?

Comment: This is not programming. OP said he has 2000 rows...

Comment: So your code is assuming two things: that the dates are for 1990 and 1991 only, and that year 1991 starts on row `5`. I find it unlikely that the OP's real data (2000 rows) will meet both criteria. Regardless, you should aim to write code that works for any type of input and makes as few assumptions as possible about the data. That's what programming is all about.